# Looking for a way to check response time of a REST api call using RSpec or any other ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rest, web-api-testing, response-time

I am developing REST API tests in ruby using RSpec. I want to check the response time of each API call. Is there any method available in any Ruby gem which provides me the required information?

Comment: What is the point of such a test?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov What do you mean by point? I just want to check the "response time" for POST and GET REST calls for the Users api. Like if we hit POST request for user creation then how much time the call would take for completing the action and vice versa.

Comment: I asked that because response time is a non-deterministic value that may vary in a wide range for the same endpoint under different conditions. Tests that involve response time will most probably be _flaky and useless at the same time_ (useless because the same endpoint's response time in a production environment under a production load will have little to no in common with the test values).

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: This answer does not make use of RSpec for measuring the elapsed time.**

You can use the **Benchmark module** provided by Ruby to measure the elapsed time for code execution.

To measure the real time taken by a block of code for execution:

```rb
require 'benchmark'

realtime = Benchmark.realtime do
  # your code here
end
puts realtime # time taken in seconds
```

Check the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) for further details about benchmarking.

Apart from the **elapsed real time**, it also lets you benchmark the **user CPU time**, **system CPU time** and t**he sum of the user and system CPU times**.